# How can I do this integration that involves tensors?

Tags: integration, tensor-products, tensors, index-notation

I'm currently studying Continuum Mechanics, and I came across with this integration, which allows the computation of a quantity called strain energy:

$$\int_\emptyset^{\varepsilon_{ij}} \sigma_{pq}d\varepsilon_{pq}=\int_\emptyset^{\varepsilon_{ij}} C_{pqkl}\varepsilon_{kl}d\varepsilon_{pq}=\frac{1}{2}C_{ijkl}\varepsilon_{kl}\varepsilon_{ij}$$

where $C_{pqkl}$ and $\varepsilon_{kl}$ are, respectively, a constant 4th-order tensor and a 2nd-order tensor.

I know how to deal with derivatives of tensors and other kind of operations but not with integrals. Can you explain me please how to obtain the second equality? Do you know any book that explains well such operations of tensors?

By the way, $C_{pqkl}$ and $\varepsilon_{kl}$ have the following symmetries:

- $C_{pqkl}=C_{qpkl}=C_{pqlk}=C_{klpq}$
- $\varepsilon_{kl}=\varepsilon_{lk}$

Comment: Are you summing over repeated indices? If yes, $i,j$ is summed over on the right, but not on the left?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I am looking at it and it seems so, but the left is summed over pq, and then ij is substituted for this.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes. I'm summing over repeated indices, all of them.

Comment: Of course you could solve your problem by actually writing it out, letting the variables go from 0to 1.

Comment: Well where does the $i,j$ from the left go? As it stands, LHS is 2nd order but the quantity on the right is a scalar, right?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yeah, I agree, the left looks like the coordinates of a tensor, the right, a scalar. He need to sort these problems out before any progress can be made.

Comment: This is how it is presented in my professor's lecture notes. The result is equivalent to $\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon\cdot C[\varepsilon]$. The indices are summed in the left too.